# MySQL mostrar registros de una tabla como columnas de otra

Tags: mysql, pivot

Tengo una tabla `articulos`

```
-------------------------  
|id|descripcion|color   |  
|--|-----------|--------|  
|1 |caja       |rojo    |  
|2 |baul       |azul    |  
|3 |cofre      |amarillo|  
-------------------------
```

Y otra tabla `atributos`

```
---------------------------  
|id |id_art|nombre |valor |
|---|------|-------|------|  
|1  |1     |alto   |150   |
|2  |1     |ancho  |300   |
|3  |1     |peso   |12    |
|4  |1     |stock  |8     |
|5  |2     |alto   |100   |
|6  |2     |ancho  |200   |
|7  |2     |peso   |10    |
|8  |3     |ancho  |300   |
---------------------------
```

Lo que necesito es mediante una query de consulta, lograr que los atributos de un articulo se comporten como columnas para filtrar por los valores de los mismos, o sea:

```
-----------------------------------------------  
|id|descripcion|color   |alto|ancho|peso|stock|  
|--|-----------|--------|----|-----|----|-----|  
|1 |caja       |rojo    |150 |300  |12  |8    |  
|2 |baul       |azul    |100 |200  |10  |null |  
|3 |cofre      |amarillo|null|300  |null|null |  
-----------------------------------------------
```

para de esta manera filtrar por los mismos o mostrarlos.
`select * from articulos where alto = 150 and ancho = 300`

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: no hay alguna llave foránea que relacione las tablas?

Comment: La relación es `articulos.id = atributos.id_art`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Consegui el listado que necesitas, con la instrucción **case when** y **sum**

```
select ar.id, ar.descripcion, ar.color, 
  sum(case when at.nombre = "alto"  then valor end) as alto,
  sum(case when at.nombre = "ancho" then valor end) as ancho,
  sum(case when at.nombre = "peso"  then valor end) as peso,
  sum(case when at.nombre = "stock" then valor end) as stock 
from articulos ar inner join atributos at
              on ar.id = at.id_art 
group by 1,2,3 ;
```

Comment: @Marcelo, consegui la query que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @PatrickAguello. De hecho, es precisamente la solucion que tambien encontré en este otra consulta: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose).

Answer (score 0):

1. En SQL no hay forma, mediante queries, de trasponer las filas a columnas.
2. Si lo que deseas es filtrar por un **where** puedes solucionarlo mediante la siguiente consulta:

   ```
   SELECT a.Id, a.descripcion, a.color, a2.nombre, a2.valor  
   FROM articulos AS a
   INNER JOIN atributos AS a2
       ON (a.Id = a2.Id_art)
   WHERE (a2.nombre = 'alto' and a2.valor = 150) or 
       (a2.nombre = 'ancho' and a2.valor = 300)
   ```

El resultado lo obtendrías en filas con los atributos uno debajo de otro para cada articulo. En caso de necesitarlo traspuesto, puedes llevarlo a excel y usar una tabla dinámica. Saludos.

**RESPUESTA NUEVA**
En caso de necesitar que se cumplan ambas condiciones con diferentes atributos, utilizas subqueries:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.descripcion, a.color, a2.nombre, a2.valor  
FROM articulos AS a
INNER JOIN atributos AS a2
    ON (a.Id = a2.Id_art)
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM atributos AS a3
        WHERE a.Id = a3.Id_art AND 
            a3.nombre = 'alto' AND 
            a3.valor = 150) >=1  AND 
      ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM atributos AS a3
        WHERE a.Id = a3.Id_art AND 
            a3.nombre = 'ancho' and 
           a3.valor = 300) >=1
```

Los Subqueries cuentan los registros donde se cumplen tus condiciones en los atributos, si dan mayor o igual a 1 en cada uno de ellos, cumple la condición que buscas.

Comment: Gracias Rostan, pero eso lo hice, y el problema es que la consulta trae los articulos que cumplan una u otra condicion, no ambas al mismo tiempo.
De todos modos, gracias por responder.

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta, espero te dirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, la solución más accesible a tu problema (a mi forma de ver) es realizar un JOIN, (puedes obtener más información sobre los tipos de JOIN [aquí](http://www.edu4java.com/es/sql/sql5.html)). Destacar que si hubieses organizado la columna asignandole el nombre y después dandole los valores (respetando el id de articulos), sería mucho más sencillo (y lógico).

Básicamente la consulta(que se me ocurre) que más se aproxime a lo que deseas es:

```
SELECT * FROM articulos JOIN atributos ON articulos.id = atributos.id_art WHERE atributos.id_art = 1 AND IF (atributos.nombre = 'alto' AND atributos.valor = 150,TRUE,FALSE) OR IF(atributos.nombre = 'ancho' AND atributos.valor = 300,TRUE,FALSE)
```

La respuesta a esta consulta (basandonos en los datos de tu tabla) son los valores: ancho = 300 y alto = 150 (ver imagen), confirmando que existen estos valores para el articulo (id.art) 1.

Ejemplo gráfico (click en la imagen para ver mejor):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, para este caso, la caja cumple con los dos atributos, puesto a que si no tuviese por ejemplo un alto de 150, aparecería solo ancho = 300, confirmando que no cumple con los dos requisitos.

Es decir, funciona 'a la inversa'.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un Doble Join

1. Te obtiene los articulos que tengan el alto en 150
2. De los articulos obtenidos, obtiene los que tengan el ancho en 300

   SELECT art.Id, art.descripcion, art.color, a_alto.nombre, a_alto.valor
       FROM articulos AS art
       INNER JOIN atributos AS a_alto  ON 
           a_alto.Id     = art.Id_art AND
           a_alto.nombre = 'alto'     AND
           a_alto.valor  = 150
       INNER JOIN atributos AS a_ancho  ON 
           a_ancho.Id     = art.Id_art AND
           a_ancho.nombre = 'ancho'     AND
           a_ancho.valor  = 300